# android sqLite prob with where clause

Tags: android

I am building a cursor for a select query.   The WHERE section lookup value refers to a variable which is a path so it has several full stops in it.

The query doesnt like this and errors , the error says a col doesn't exist named with a name which is the lookup value i.e the path with stops in it. If I use the sqlEscape util on the variable it doesnt cause an error but the lookup fails.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: some code would be handy...  Guessing is fun but probably not that useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a bit of your code it is hard to say but I'm guessing you are putting your where clause together like this:

```
String value = "some.thing.or.other";
String where = "FIELD = " + value;
```

Try building a parameterized where clause instead

```
String value = "some.thing.or.other";
String where = "FIELD = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = fDbOpener.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor results = db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS_LIST, where, new String[] { value }, null, null, null);
```

When you run the query method now, SQLite will substitute your value into the where clause specifically as a value - it won't try to interpret the value in any way so it can't mistake the full stops for syntax.